# Нянь та балерун?

Tags: іменники, розмовна-українська

Питання стосується двох відомих професій, які вважаються жіночими, але можуть також виконуватися чоловіками.
Отож, якщо танцівниця балету називається балерина, то як назвати чоловіка який займається балетом? Таке ж саме питання стосується професії няні. 
В словниках української мови, а також у російських академічних словниках мені не вдалося знайти відповідників, то невже у нашій мові справді немає данних відповідників і можна використовувати лише "танцівник балету" та "доглядач за дитиною"?

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, я б сказав, що це схоже питання, але не те саме.

Comment: Ще схоже: [«Назви чоловічих професій, які історично були лише жіночими: ПОВІЯ»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3358).

Answer (score 0):

[Словник української мови у 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=179952&page=104)

> **БАЛЕРУ́Н**, **~а**, *чоловічий рід, **розмовне*** Артист балету; танцівник.
>
> *На гастролі поїде ціла трупа – 120 осіб, серед яких балерини, балеруни, симфонічний оркестр, художники і технічні працівники* (з газ.); *Стрункий балерун;*
>
> У порівнянні. *А вишибала цілує ручки нареченій, розкланюється, як балерун* (А. Крижанівський).

Слова ***"нянь"*** в словниках не знайшла.

Проте в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/njanjko) присутне

> **НЯНЬКО** а, *чоловічий рід,* ***діалектне*** Тато. *Почав Іванко казати своєму нянькові: — Я, няньку, йду світа пізнати* (Андрій Калин,
> Закарп. казки, 1955, 12);

Частіше в розмові використовують *няня-чоловік*, однозначного заміника немає.